# How to merge these two queries into 1 Google Sheets

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, import, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

I m looking for a way to use these below two queries into 1 I have tried a lot but everytime got an error. I have searched as well on google but nothing find. your help will be appreciated

**No .1**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(UPPER(QUERY({IMPORTRANGE(Links!D10,"Sheet16!A3:AX1000"),IF(ISDATE_STRICT(IMPORTRANGE(Links!D10,"Sheet16!G3:G1000")),"No Show","Checked")}, "Select Col1, Col10, Col44, Col11, Col12, Col13, Col14, Col18, Col20, Col21, Col22, Col23, Col25, Col27, Col28, Col29, Col32, Col33, Col34, Col35, Col38, Col39, Col40, Col41, Col42, Col43 WHERE Col12 is not null ORDER BY Col10",0)))
```

**NO. 2**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(UPPER(QUERY({IMPORTRANGE(Links!D11,"Sheet16!A3:AX1000"),IF(ISDATE_STRICT(IMPORTRANGE(Links!D11,"Sheet16!G3:G1000")),"No Show","Checked")}, "Select Col1, Col10, Col44, Col11, Col12, Col13, Col14, Col18, Col20, Col21, Col22, Col23, Col25, Col27, Col28, Col29, Col32, Col33, Col34, Col35, Col38, Col39, Col40, Col41, Col42, Col43 WHERE Col12 is not null ORDER BY Col10",0)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(UPPER(QUERY({{
 IMPORTRANGE(Links!D10, "Sheet16!A3:AX1000"); 
 IMPORTRANGE(Links!D11, "Sheet16!A3:AX1000")}, IF(ISDATE_STRICT({
 IMPORTRANGE(Links!D10, "Sheet16!G3:G1000"); 
 IMPORTRANGE(Links!D11, "Sheet16!G3:G1000")}), "No Show", "Checked")}, 
 "select Col1,Col10,Col44,Col11,Col12,Col13,Col14,Col18,Col20,Col21,Col22,Col23,Col25,Col27,Col28,Col29,Col32,Col33,Col34,Col35,Col38,Col39,Col40,Col41,Col42,Col43 
  where Col12 is not null 
  order by Col10", 0)))
```